# Excel to Libreoffice macro conversion - RefreshTable

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to run an Excel VBA macro from LibreOffice 7.1 that breaks here:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable 
    Next pt    
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select

End Sub
```

The function `pt.RefreshTable` aparently does not exists on calc's, does anyone know how can I replace it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[Refresh](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XDataPilotTable.html#refresh)** method instead of `RefreshTable`. Also note the difference between `.getDataPilotTables()` and `.PivotTables`

```
Sub updatePivotData
Dim oActiveSheet As Variant
Dim oDataPilotTables As Variant
Dim oTable As Variant
    oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()
    oDataPilotTables = oActiveSheet.getDataPilotTables()
    For Each oTable in oDataPilotTables
        oTable.refresh()
    Next oTable
End Sub
```